# Any way to pass custom additional args to cucumber and parse them?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, command-line-interface

For the moment to set the runtime options of my tests (platform url, database, etc....) I'm using a YAML file that I parse using `YAML.load_file` before launching the test itself. For debugging/development purpose I was wondering if there was any way to pass custom custom cli args and parse them in the same way. For example `--debug-database <database hostname>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use environment variables for this

from: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Environment-Variables

> When you are Running Features it can sometimes be handy to pass
>   special values to Cucumber so that they can be picked up in your Step
>   Definitions. You can easily do this on the command line:
>
> cucumber FOO=BAR --format progress features You can now pick up
>   ENV['FOO'] in ruby (for example in env.rb or a step definition) and
>   take actions according to the value

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should add a 'rtfm' tag to this question ;)